# Finding average and moving average at any level

Tags: t-sql

I have a situation 
I have a table which has 3 columns:

1. Product_ID
2. Scheduled_date_time
3. Arrival_date_time

Write a query to get the total number of delayed products, the average delay in minutes and the moving average all aggregated at week level, using the Scheduled_date_time as reference for the aggregation.

Delay is when a product arrives after its `Scheduled_date_time`.

I used this query to get total and average at week level:

```
select week_num, 
sum(Isdelayed),
avg(Timediff_Inmins)

from 
(
select product_id,
       Scheduled_date_time,
       Arrival_date_time,
       case when Scheduled_date_time<Arrival_date_time then 1 else 0 end Isdelayed,
       datediff(MINUTE,Scheduled_date_time,Arrival_date_time) as Timediff_Inmins,
       datepart(week,Scheduled_date_time) as week_num
from products

) x
group by x.week_num 

--Query below gives me moving average at week level of aggregation 
select x.week_num,AVG(Timediff_Inmins) OVER (ORDER BY week_num ASC ROWS 6 PRECEDING) as Moving_Average_PerWeek
from 
(
select product_id,
       Scheduled_date_time,
       Arrival_date_time,
       case when Scheduled_date_time<Arrival_date_time then 1 else 0 end Isdelayed,
       datediff(MINUTE,Scheduled_date_time,Arrival_date_time) as Timediff_Inmins,
       datepart(week,Scheduled_date_time) as week_num
from products
) x
group by x.week_num,x.Timediff_Inmins
```

Not sure if Im going in the right direction as I do not have the sample data.
I came across this question from somewhere.

Getting Total and average at week level isn't an issue for me but getting total,average and moving average all aggregated at week level, using the Scheduled_date_time as reference for the aggregation is the real challenge for me here. Reason being total and average can be put in one query grouped by week_num but cant put moving average in the same query so I end up with 2 queries and again not sure if they are exactly rite.

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: Yes I did but I'm confused at average and moving average at week level aggregation , I'm a junior developer - my query gives me total and average at week level and not sure if its right select week_num, sum(Isdelayed),
avg(Timediff_Inmins) from (select product_id,Scheduled_date_time,Arrival_date_time,
       case when Scheduled_date_time<Arrival_date_time then 1 else 0 end Isdelayed,datediff(MINUTE,Scheduled_date_time,Arrival_date_time) as Timediff_Inmins, datepart(week,Scheduled_date_time) as week_num
from products) x
group by x.week_num

Comment: Edit your question and include this query.  You probably also want to show us sample data.

Comment: This query gives me moving average but im not sure if this is rite and also i want to get results in one query -select x.week_num,AVG(Timediff_Inmins) OVER (ORDER BY week_num ASC ROWS 6 PRECEDING) as Moving_Average_PerWeek
from 
(
select product_id,
       Scheduled_date_time,
       Arrival_date_time,
       case when Scheduled_date_time<Arrival_date_time then 1 else 0 end Isdelayed,
    datediff(MINUTE,Scheduled_date_time,Arrival_date_time) as Timediff_Inmins,
    datepart(week,Scheduled_date_time) as week_num
from products
) x
group by x.week_num,x.Timediff_Inmins

Comment: I do not have sample data so Im not sure how exactly I can tackle this question. So i want to see how senior developers see this question and what would they think to solve this question.

Comment: Senior developers ask for sample data because they know it is needed.